# How To Remove Row If Combination of Columns Are Same From Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this.

```
'Column1' 'Column2' 'Column3'
'cat'     'bat'.    '100'
'toy'    'flower'.  '80'
'bat'    'cat'      '100'
```

If combination of Column 1 and Column 2 is same in this case cat and bat in row 1 and row 3, I want to remove 1 row.

The resulting data frame should only have.

```
'Column1'  'Column2' 'Column3'
'cat'.     'bat'.     '100'
'toy'.     'flower'.  '80'
```

Answer (score 4):

First sorting by [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) for improve performance, create `DataFrame` and filter by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted mask by `~`:

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Column1','Column2']], axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated()

df1 = df[~mask]
print (df1)
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'cat'     'bat'   '100'
1   'toy'  'flower'    '80'
```